# How to blit an image for a second or two over the background

Tags: python, pygame

So I'm trying to blit an image over the background for a second or two when the score hits 50. I used this:

```
if score == 50:

                horrificImage = pygame.image.load('Image.jpg').convert()
                clock.tick(1)
                pygame.time.delay(1500)
                thescreen.blit(horrificImage, (0, 0))
```

It seems to delay for a second and a half and blit the image but only very briefly. How would I make it so it displays for one/one and a half seconds? I'm sorry if it seems brief, only quite new to pygame and not sure how to word it!

**EDIT**
It's like it's delaying it right, but blitting it right at the last frame, not for the whole duration of the delay, like it want it to.

Comment: Do you have a main loop where you draw the rest of your game? Do you want everything else to stop while this image is shown, or should the game go on?

Comment: Don't you want to blit the image *before* you enter the delay?

Comment: Yes, I do want the whole game to stop. I mean, if I blit the image before I delay, the game just pauses and doesn't show the image.. If I blit after clock.tick and before the delay, the image shows up but for like literally a couple of milliseconds. I can put the whole code if you want to take a look at that.

Comment: Don't use `delay`, `wait`, `sleep` if you have animation. It stops program and your animation for the moment. Use `pygame.time.get_ticks()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Blit is what gets the image ready for the screen, but doesn't display it.  You should blit, then update the display with pygame.display.update() before the delay.

Comment: Thankyou! :) and thanks for taking the time to read my question!

Answer (score 0):

Use `pygame.time.get_ticks()` to get current time and compare with `time_to_blit`

```
# before mainloop
horrificImage = pygame.image.load('Image.jpg').convert()
time_to_blit = None

# in mainloop

# when you increase score
    score += 1
    if score == 50: # you can do even more: score == 50 or score == 100
        time_to_blit = pygame.time.get_ticks() + 1500 # 1.5 seconds

# when you blit images    
if time_to_blit: # you don't even need: score == 50
    thescreen.blit(horrificImage, (0, 0))
    if pygame.time.get_ticks() >= time_to_blit:
        time_to_blit = None
```

BTW: don't load image everytime in loop - you waste time. Do it once before mainloop.

Comment: Thankyou! That's very helpful :) also, thanks for taking your time to read my question!